# How do I specify the lon,lat ordering in CSW bounding box request?

Tags: xml, csw

I'm confused about the order of the lat/lon pairs when a CSW BBOX request is specified.

On [this Geoportal Server CSW page](http://webhelp.esri.com/geoportal_extension/9.3.1/index.htm#geoportal_csw_cmpnts.htm), there is a `GetRecords` example where clearly the ordering is (lon,lat):

```
<ogc:BBOX>
  <ogc:PropertyName>ows:BoundingBox</ogc:PropertyName> 
  <gml:Envelope>
    <gml:lowerCorner>-118.3 32.1</gml:lowerCorner> 
    <gml:upperCorner>-87.1 45.2</gml:upperCorner> 
  </gml:Envelope>
</ogc:BBOX>
```

but on this [Data.gov example gist](https://gist.github.com/kalxas/5ab6237b4163b0fdc930), it says:

"bounding box queries and responses always use axis order latitude longitude"

Is there a way to specify which order the request is using to avoid ambiquity (and possibly incorrect query responses)?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the discussion above, the answer is that the coordinates are specified in the order determined by the coordinate system you are using.  The EPSG codes all specify (lat,lon) order for geographic coordinates, while specifying (x,y) order for projected coordinates.

The OGC, however, in (http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=30575) defined a coordinate system transform for (lon,lat) ordering with WGS84 geographic coordinates, so if the CSW server supports it, you can specify:

```
<ogc:BBOX>
   <ogc:PropertyName>ows:BoundingBox</ogc:PropertyName>
   <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84">
     <gml:lowerCorner> -158.4 20.7</gml:lowerCorner>
     <gml:upperCorner> -157.2 21.6</gml:upperCorner>
   </gml:Envelope>
</ogc:BBOX>
```

which should result in the same results as

```
<ogc:BBOX>
  <ogc:PropertyName>ows:BoundingBox</ogc:PropertyName>
  <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326">
    <gml:lowerCorner> 20.7 -158.4</gml:lowerCorner>
    <gml:upperCorner> 21.6 -157.2</gml:upperCorner>
  </gml:Envelope>
</ogc:BBOX>
```

This in fact does work in queries to pyCSW, in versions 1.10.1 and higher.  See: https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/issues/287

See also this related issue:  [Is there an EPSG code to specify WGS84 in (lon,lat) order instead of (lat,lon)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124077/is-there-an-epsg-code-to-specify-wgs84-in-lon-lat-order-instead-of-lat-lon)

Answer (score 0):

The Gist is authoritative iirc.  Having said this, the safest way is to be explicit and specify an `srsName` with the correct axis order, and [pycsw](http://pycsw.org) (OWSLib) will detect the `srsName` and process as per the axis ordering rules.

An example can be found at https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/blob/master/tests/suites/default/post/GetRecords-filter-bbox-reproject.xml

Comment: So if I want to ensure (lat,lon) order, I could specify:  `<gml:Envelope srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326">`  Is that right?

Comment: I think that this is authoritative http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=20555. OGC standards are not very easy to interpret. Your both examples are using "QueryConstraintType" of "ogc:Filter" and especially "version" 1.1.0 which means that for finding the correct syntax next step is to go to feature encoding standard v. 1.1.0 https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=51130. That tells that BBOX is "a very common bounding box constraint based on the gml:Envelope geometry". So finally take a right version of GML standard from http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml.

Comment: Surely the spec is authorative

Comment: @user30184, do you know which of the many OGC GML standard docs would be the "right version", in this case?

Comment: @RichSignell CSW uses GML 3.1.1.

Comment: So this document? http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=4700

Comment: So you take this seriously. That's good but for example GML 3.2.1 standard is 437 pages. If you build your filter in GML 3.1.1 and give srsName as "urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326" then lat,lon is for sure right. Only hope that the CSW server understands the urn-style srsName. Probably it does.

Comment: The GML 3.1.1 document doesn't appear to add insight here.  It just says "Envelope defines an extent using a pair of positions defining opposite corners in arbitrary dimensions." I think the key thing is that the order of the coordinates in the bounding box specification is supposed to follow the CRS.  But in practice, it seems that many of the CSW services I am trying to query are just assuming (lon,lat) ordering and ignoring the CRS specification.  So is there a specification of EPSG that specifies (lon,lat) ordering?  If there was I could cover these sins...

Comment: Coincidentally this fresh and long thread on SpatiaLite forum is about axis order https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/rhHRB8MhhUE