# Python - Calculate image extent based on center coordinate, number of pixels and rotation angles

Tags: python, gdal, coordinates

I have images with a center geo-coordinate and rotation angles in x- and y-direction. Now I want to georeference them by setting up a GeoTransform object. For non-rotated images, this is easy, using

```
ul_x = cent_x + ((cols / 2.) * image_resolution)
ul_y = cent_y + ((rows / 2.) * image_resolution)
geotrans = (ul_x, image_resolution, 0, ul_y, 0, -image_resolution
```

But how can I calculate the actual upper left corner coordinate in case of a rotated image?

I guess there is a way to somehow utilize `affine.Affine` in a similar way as given in the accapted answer of [Retrieve pixel value with geographic coordinate as input with gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221292/retrieve-pixel-value-with-geographic-coordinate-as-input-with-gdal), but I don't know how.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something from this mail thread https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2020-December/053179.html.

Comment: Actually the guy I'm already in contact with on that issue. Was not aware that he already posted it there.