# Get elevation from a GeoTIFF file given latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have written the following code that return the elevation given longitude and latitude from a GeoTIFF file:

```
    private static double getValue( String filePath, double longitude, double latitude) throws Exception {

        gdal.AllRegister();

        Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(filePath, gdalconstConstants.GA_ReadOnly);

        String projection = dataset.GetProjection();
        double[] transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform();

        SpatialReference src = new SpatialReference();
        src.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
        SpatialReference dst = new SpatialReference(projection);
        CoordinateTransformation coordinateTransformation = new CoordinateTransformation(src, dst);


        double[] xy = coordinateTransformation.TransformPoint(longitude, latitude);

        float[] result = new float[1];
        int[] band = {1};
        
        int x = (int)(((xy[0] - transform[0]) / transform[1]));
        int y = (int)(((xy[1] - transform[3]) / transform[5]));
        int readRaster = dataset.ReadRaster(x, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, result, band);
        if (readRaster == 3){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        double elevation = result[0];
        return elevation;
    }
```

I am working with the following geoTiff file https://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/gdal_eg/

and I compare the result with the `gdallocationinfo` command .

the problem is that I do not get the same x,y pixels

for example if I use:

> "longitude":-117.631169,
> "latitude" : 33.722355

In the code I get x = 14 and y = 408 and elevation = 132

but if I use it with `gdallocationinfo cea.tif -wgs84 -117.631169 33.722355` I get x = 16 and y = 408 and elevation = 90

Another issue that I had that I notice that the elevation of the lon lat define in the example are not the real elevation in an elevation finder tool https://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm which there it says 579.00 m

Comment: can somebody help please?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code, based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415337/219296, which should work just fine:

```py
class ALOSTile():
    def __init__(self, tile_path):
        """
        Load a tile, and cache it. Individual tiles are relatively
        small, so for performance we preload the entire tile's
        elevation data into RAM.
        """
        self.tile_path = tile_path
        self.dataset = gdal.Open(tile_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

        if self.dataset is None:
            raise Exception(f'Could not load GDAL file{tile_path}')

        self.grid = self.dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

    def lookup(self, lat, lon):
        """
        see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415337/219296
        """
        try:
            forward_transform = self.dataset.GetGeoTransform()
            reverse_transform = gdal.InvGeoTransform(forward_transform)
            x, y = [int(v) for v in gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(
                reverse_transform, lon, lat)]
            return int(self.grid[y][x])

        except:
            return None
```