# WPS execute request cannot parse outputbbox

Tags: geoserver, wps

I am trying to build a WPS request to Geoserver with a url using KVPs.  I've gotten this far by working backwards from the WPS request demo page:

https://.../geoserver/wps?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=Execute&identifier=gs:BarnesSurface&DataInputs=valueAttr%3dcat;data%3d%40xlink%3ahref%3dhttps://.../geoserver/ows%3Fservice=WFS%26version=1.0.0%26request=GetFeature%26typeName=sf:archsites;scale%3d10;outputWidth%3D100;outputHeight%3D100;outputBBOX=-90,-180,90,180,EPSG:4326

It seems that I'm not putting the outputBBOX parameter in correctly.  I've been having trouble finding documentation on formatting this properly in a non-xml format.  Any ideas on how to structure the last parameter? I'm assuming it's minlat, minlong, maxlat, maxlong, projection, but it's obviously incorrect because I get the following error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 https://gis.akrf.com:8443/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>
     Failed to parse the bounding box Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Because you specify your CRS as EPSG:4326, you have to provide coordinates in lon, lat order  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/124050/2856

Comment: rather than reverse engineering the call read the [specification](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wps)

Comment: I found this example in the specification:   BoundingBoxData values – Examples: 
 51.9,7.0,53.0,8.0,EPSG:4326  --  the only difference I can see is the lats/longs  are not integers.  I will try making the values decimals and see if that works

Comment: I added decimals to the lat longs and tried both long,lat and lat,long order and still have the same error.